# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\attendance_manager\android\build.gradle' line: 26

Tags: java, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\attendance_manager\android\build.gradle' line: 26 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\attendance_manager\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\dell.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\6kf7hlj2razsy2gytva6h994n). > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63 * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights.[image: Open this image for output]

I tried to remove invalidate caches , after that i restart my computer , after that i unistall my flutter app in my device but, nothig happen.

Answer (score 1):

Check your java version , if your **Java** version is **18,19** or **20** delete your latest version and try to use **Java-8** or **Java-11**.

-> I tried Java **version 11** , My error was solve